# Is there a way to convert from a dropout frame / fork to a quick release / thru axle?

Tags: mountain-bike

just really want to know if I can, because I am working on a project bike and can't find good parts for a dropout frame.

Comment: What do you mean by a 'dropout frame'? Hubs with either quick release or threaded axles fit into slotted dropouts. Frames cannot generally be converted to through axle hubs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short of cutting off the dropouts and welding/brazing/bonding on through-axle fixtures, no, you can't convert between them.

Answer (score 0):

Some frames are convertible between QR and TA, but they are not common (and probably less and less so).  I don't recall seeing forks that are convertible.

What parts do you have right now (frame? fork? wheels/hubs?) and what problem are trying to solve?

Comment: just working on a project bike and seeing what the internet has for my questions